# How do I implement a JavaScript interpreter into a C# game?

Tags: c#, javascript, scripting

I'm trying to create a hacking game where players design programs and hack other people's stuff. Users write their programs in JavaScript. I'm aiming for a [hackmud-style](http://store.steampowered.com/app/469920/hackmud/) system, where user programs can interact with the host game, for example, transferring funds.

Trouble is, I don't know where to start. I'm using C# to develop my game. Everything I found online for using JavaScript in C# interprets the script as a program on the host computer. This is a problem because I don't want the user code to have access to the host computer, just the game. Is there a standard architecture for a project like this?

Comment: That's a nice question! However I wouldn't proceed like this. Program the game in whatever language you like better. As for user input you could use a template and parse it instead of actual "code".

Comment: Example: you could have a predefined snippet like: ''connectTo.bank({username: test1, password: test2});'' and parse it to get desired values.

Comment: @Valamorde Writing an own interpreter for a scripting language is a project which seems easy at first glance, but becomes amazingly complicated when you start looking at the details. Using an existing interpreter is almost always a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Microsoft's [ClearScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/ClearScript). This includes an examples page that will provide the basics of setting up an interface where the script will interact with your game.

I have to admit to not having used it myself (though I have considered it in the past for a game, and have used C# scripting using Roslyn instead), but looking at the Examples and FAQTutorial pages reveal that it should be a simple task to implement a way for a users script to interact with your game.